# Pregunta: ¿existe algún método o función de JavaScript que te devuelva el tamaño de un arreglo que no sea la función length? agradeciendo, gracias

Tags: javascript

La pregunta obedece a que una plataforma educativa donde se monta un reto con este lenguaje de programación no interpreta el método length para un arreglo a la que solo debe ingresar un máximo de 30 registros (mediante un botón llamado Registrar) de un formulario de varios campos diseñado con HTML. El reto dice exactamente así: Implementar una función almacenarRegistros() que permita
guardar la información registrada por parte del usuario en el formulario de registro. Se debe almacenar en un arreglo cada uno de los registros de los campos del formulario, esto se debe realizar cada vez que el usuario presione el botón “REGISTRAR”. Por ultimo, tenga en cuenta que el tamaño máximo que se debe garantizar en el arreglo es de 30 registros.

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado? Pégale un vistazo a https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Solo guarda el número de registros almacenados en una variable y listo. Cada vez que almacenes un nuevo registro, compruebas el valor de esa variable y  para garantizar que sea menor que 30 y la vas incrementando. No necesitas usar length

Comment: El reto habla de implementar la función `almacenarRegistros` si no interpreta la función `length` puede ser que la estás usando mal. Agrega el código que has hecho.

Comment: No le entiendo, mi código lo tengo de la siguiente manera:                                         
     var numRegistro = 30;                                                                                              
     if(registro.length > numRegistro) {
        alert("Superó el número máximo de registros permitidos: (30) ");
        return registro.splice(registro.length-1) 
    }